# What’s the effect of leaving an item on another’s property?

Tags: england-and-wales, property, chattel

Bob is hanging out at Alice’s house. He leaves but forgets to take with him his phone, leaving it there.

She picks it up and can’t be bothered to contact him about it so she just chucks it in the bin without telling anyone.

What’s the legal position?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't be asked to contact him"?  And what do you mean by legal "position"?

Comment: It means she's too lazy to or otherwise doesn't feel like doing it.

Comment: Does it change the legal position if Bob secures his phone with a chain?  ;)

Comment: The correct spelling is "can't be arsed".

Comment: @Lag the alternative spelling - can’t be asked is a known [malapropism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism)

Answer (score 4):

In the act of disposing of the phone Alice has appropriated it, and is likely guilty of [theft](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/60/crossheading/definition-of-theft).